# AdvancedEncryptionStandard in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, aes

This is my code for converting a normal string to AES encrypted string :

```
public class AES2

{

    private static AES2 aes = new AES2( );

    private AES2() { }

    public static AES2 getInstance( ) {
        return aes;
    }

    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey ;
    private static byte[] key ;

    private static String decryptedString;
    private static String encryptedString;

    public static void setKey(String myKey){


        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println(key.length);
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
            System.out.println(key.length);
            System.out.println(new String(key,"UTF-8"));
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");


        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt)
    {
        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            encryptedString =     (Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: "+e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt)
    {
        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt));
            decryptedString = bytes.toString();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: "+e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've included commons-codec-1.10.jar in the /libs folder and added it as library.

I'm getting compilation errors while compiling :

1) error: cannot find symbol method encodeBase64String(byte[]), for

```
encryptedString =     (Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
```

2) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to byte[], for

```
byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt));
```

I've checked and the functions calls match perfectly, but I have no idea why I'm getting these errors.

What am I doing wrong?

PS : The code is from : http://aesencryption.net/#Java-aes-encryption-example

Comment: check your import class for base64,or update your question code with imports.

Comment: On the PHP server, I'm using  org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64, so won't that cause trouble?

Comment: It might work out. try to change it to android.util.Base64 and execute, it will be faster to know.

Comment: Working on it!!

Comment: Doesn't work!!!

Comment: did you changed the method accordingly? It has additional parameter.

Comment: String encrypted = Base64.encodeToString(yourbytearray, Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: Yes, made the changes. Compiles. But, inconsistent results. The same string is encrypted to different string over the client and server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126330/discussion-between-arjun-issar-and-karan-mer).

Comment: Ah, don't use that code! It's terrible. It's very insecure and the site doesn't even provide compatible code between Java and PHP. You really should use something like RNCryptor which provides a consistent code base for multiple languages and is really secure.

Comment: Any resolution on this? I am looking for the same.